# Difference in NSMutableArray declaration

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

What is the difference between `[NSMutableArray array]` and `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[NSMutableArray array]
```

returns an autoreleased array.

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

returns a retained array.

You don't own the autoreleased array, so you don't have to release it. You own the retained one (with alloc), so you have to release it.

Comment: do you have to release it in the dealloc method?

Comment: If it's a property, release it in dealloc. Otherwise release it when you're done with it. Typically you'll only retain it if you want it to stick around.

Comment: what if it's an instance variable declared in the .h file?

Comment: I'd treat that the same as a property. Properties are just more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

`[NSMutableArray array]` is equivalent to `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`.